# Devise 2.2.3 always shows signed in notification before signing in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, devise

Devise 2.2.3 after upgrade due to rails security issues, always shows signed in notification message before signing in, and when I try to login, it returns

```
Started POST "/users/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-02-17 00:55:34 +0530
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"Uri7L+RS+l3Nwjln1cBLfwxfMWEdEYz3gWEHyXpbRPc=", "user"=>{"email"=>"abcdedf@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Sign in"}
Completed 401 Unauthorized in
```

Rails version: 3.1.x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This strange behavior came up because of controller action caching, disabling it at environments/production.rb solved this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

In config/initializers/devise.rb

True by default.

```
config.http_authenticatable_on_xhr = false
```

Comment: Did you make sure to restart the server after editing a config file?

Comment: Try adding 'config.navigational_formats = [:html, "*/*", :"*/*"]' to the same initializer file and restarting your server.

Comment: yes, and I found out that, it is due to controller action caching, disabled it in production.rb and not it is working fine.